# Detox test stalls when moving between text inputs iPad

Tags: earlgrey, detox

I have followed the instructions at https://github.com/wix/detox, created a few simple tests and run them successfully on an iPhone sim. However, when using an iPad (ios 11.2) it stalls after entering text in the first of two text inputs (for a login screen). My test is as follows

```
it('should log in and take user to feed', async () => {
  await element(by.id('email')).typeText('email')
  await element(by.id('password')).typeText('password')
  await element(by.id('loginButton')).tap()
  await expect(element(by.id('feed'))).toBeVisible()
})
```

As I say, all tests pass on iPhone but not iPad, and when viewing the sim it clearly hangs between the first and second text field. I've also tried `replaceText()` which results in a failed test, I think due to this issue with EarlGrey https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/151.

I searched around the problem and I think it's related to this https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/issues/239#issuecomment-247737738. If anyone knows a fix I'd be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it generally passing for you if you directly use EarlGrey? Can you provide an error log? Also, does detox use it with CocoaPods?

Comment: I haven't tried using EarlGrey directly - I'll try that out and get back with results + any error logs I can get.  
  
Using detox there aren't really any error logs, it simply times out eventually and the test fails, but you can see/hear that it is typing fine in the first input box but then hanging when moving to the second.  
  
As far as I can see perusing the source code, CocaPods is not in use in detox, but I might be missing it - https://github.com/wix/detox/tree/master/detox/ios

Comment: Hmm, then it should be pulling it from Source. That's odd. Is the submodule tied to a commit number?